# IIS 7: Application Pools configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, application-pools

We recently had to move some of my websites from Apache to IIS 7 (on Windows Server 2008).

Now I have to put my hands on it, and I found this application pools configuration (I obscured websites names for privacy):

[image]

I don't need ASP.NET since ColdFusion is our application server.

My question is: **what are exactly application pools? how do I configure them for a multi-site environment such as mine?**

What's the "Applications" number meaning for each website?

They're all different customer's websites, I want to isolate each one resource usage, and avoid one website bothering the others.

How much is this configuration wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define application pool group, so any websites running outside of that Application pool cannot affect the performance of websites in the application pool.

If you assign dedicated application pool for each website then every website will be having it's own boundary. No other website can degrade the performance.

Number of applications means how many websites are currently using the same application pool. For example, ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated Application pool is running 2 websites on it.

To remove ASP.NET try below command:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[version]\aspnet_regiis.exe -ua